# Unable to send an e-mail with MONO on Debian : TLS error

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, debian, mono

This code works on Windows and worked on my Debian server until IONOS my e-mail service provider prevented any communication with their SMTP server if the TLS version is below 1.2

```
public static bool sendEmail(string recipient, string subject, string body)
{
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxx@xxx.com", "xxx");
MailAddress to = new MailAddress(recipient);

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

string content = "test";
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
message.Subject = subject;
message.Body = content;
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.ReplyTo = from;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.ionos.fr", 587);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@xxx.com", "xxx"); 
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
}
```

This code deliver this kind of error messsage :

`System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Message could not be sent. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION at /build/mono-6.12.0.182/external/boringssl/ssl/tls_record.c:462 at Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsContext.ProcessHandshake () [0x00048] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0  at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status, System.Boolean renegotiate) [0x000da] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus,bool) at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) [0x00006] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0  at Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest.ProcessOperation (System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000fc] in <33b19a7ad5234d94abf4fd9b47566616>:0`

What can I change in the code to make it work.

When I open the communication using
`openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.ionos.fr:587`
it says that the protocol is right, TLS 1.2

Comment: Maybe don't use `client.EnableSsl = true;`? Is there an `client.EnableTls = true;` instead?